# R: can a function in a package read a text file in the same package?

Tags: sql, r

The use case is as follows: I have created a package which contains functions which run queries against a data base. Instead of defining the query in an R-script e.g. (excuse the pseudo-code):

```
house_price_query <- "select * from house_prices"
get.house_prices <- function() run_query(house_price_query)
```

Can I save the query as a text file in say `queries/house_prices.sql` and then read this text file into the query?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your file `house_prices.sql` in `inst/queries` in your package folder, and then load it from within R (once your package is installed) with :

```
system.file(file.path("queries","house_prices.sql"), package="your_package_name")
```

Comment: any reason why you used `file.path` instead of just passing the components of the path directly to `system.file`?

Comment: @Mullefa `file.path` is platform independent, so you don't have to care which separator to use on which operating system.

Comment: As in... isn't your answer above identical to `system.file("queries","house_prices.sql", package="your_package_name")`?

Comment: Hmm you're right, this seems to work too. I don't understand how the files argument to `system.file` works exactly...